# IE11 anchor tag has greater height than the image inside it

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have an image on my page that is wrapped in an anchor tag. It's pretty basic:

```
<a href="/linkedPage">
    <img src="/~/media/Image">
</a>
```

But on Internet Explorer, it's taking up extra space, and I discovered that the  tag has is bigger than the image inside it, and for some reason is not fitted to its content. This is what it looks like, with the border of the  object highlighted:

[image]

On all other browsers it looks correct.

When I apply a set height to the images, the  takes on the same height, but I can't apply a set height because the images need to be flexible and accept any image size. Why is this happening? I tried applying `display: block` and `height: auto` to both the anchor and the img, but no dice

Edit: This is the current CSS

```
a {
color: #159be6;
-moz-transition: all 100ms;
-o-transition: all 100ms;
-webkit-transition: all 100ms;
transition: all 100ms;
}
a {
color: #337ab7;
text-decoration: none;
}
normalize.less:90
a {
background-color: transparent;
}

.thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .img-responsive, 
.thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.thumbnail img {
margin-bottom: 0;
}
img {
vertical-align: middle;
}
normalize.less:186
img {
border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more code ? The rules applying to the a, to the img, etc...

Comment: Nothing, basically. I've stripped all css rules in the inspector and it's still the wrong height. I've added the css rules in the original post

Comment: It's a carousel, right ? Do all your images have the same height ?

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with flexbox

Comment: What issue was that? If you found a solution you can post it as an answer

Comment: It was "display: flex" that caused the issue,  but unfortunately I could not find any way to resolve the issue while still using flex, which I needed, other than setting a specific height on the <a> tags